# Laravel Mail::queue and supervisor

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis, supervisord

Hello I have a very strange behavaior for Laravel redis queues + supervisor.
Queues are inserted to Redis I can see them, Supervisor is working, even if I try manually start `php artisan queue:work` emails are not sent.
My configs:
**Queue:**

```
'default' => 'redis',
```

This is **log** that I get from `redis-cli monitor`

```
2choice:illuminate:queue:restart"
```

My supervisor:

```
[program:2choice]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:work --memory=256 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon --force
directory=/var/www/2choice
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=wwwu
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/2choice/storage/logs/queue.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
```

I tried also `php artisan queue:listen` but still email are not send

if I run `htop` in `cmd` I can see this 8 proccess runing.

This is how they are inserted in redis:

```
{
    "job": "mailer@handleQueuedMessage",
    "data": {
        "view": "mail.activation",
        "data": {
            "user": "dsdfs",
            "reflink": "https://www.domen.com/register/7/hrHGMgD9jwl4PmyElro86wpapmVTTdQS"
        },
        "callback": "C:32:........;}}"
    },
    "id": "yiSsPWFmBz2DfJprFJ1kD4Ti3pUdxxTR",
    "attempts": 1
}
```

`MySQL table for failed jobs` is empty

Any help or suggustion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I solved it
My app was in `maintenance mode.` running `php artisan up` solved it

Update:
You can add `evenInMaintenanceMode();`